# Bootbox Prompt multiline input text

Tags: prompt, bootbox

I want to create a bootbox with a multiline prompt. It is the default example:

```
bootbox.prompt({
  title: "What is your real name?",
  value: "makeusabrew",
  callback: function(result) {
    if (result === null) {
      Example.show("Prompt dismissed");
    } else {
      Example.show("Hi <b>"+result+"</b>");
    }
  }
});
```

But it just allow to have a inline value. I need to show a multiline value and have a multiline input text.

Answer (score 5):

I just had to add `inputType: "textarea"`

```
bootbox.prompt({
  title: "What is your real name?",
  value: "makeusabrew",
  inputType: "textarea",
  callback: function(result) {
    if (result === null) {
      Example.show("Prompt dismissed");
    } else {
      Example.show("Hi <b>"+result+"</b>");
    }
  }
});
```

It works like a charm now :)